# How to get the value of data selected in datalist in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I want to get the value of selected item in datalist in javascript. As i am working on meteor, I have a requirement for getting the value of the selected data in a `datalist`.

My code is:

```
<input type="text" list="d1" id="search" name="browser" placeholder="Search By">
<datalist id="d1">
    {{#each searched_item}}
       <option value={{this}}>{{this}}\</option>
    {{/each}} 
</datalist>
```

This is my code in my template, I have used for my form in meteor. Here searched_item is the function i have called in helper inside my js file in meteor. Now I need to get the value of selected items in `datalist` in javascript.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: Its fine with me if i get answer in  Jquery or Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create​ an event handler in your template to handle the form submit.  Then use the  event object to get the value from your datalist.

Remember a [datalist](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp) just provides an autocomplete feature for a text input. So you just need to get the value of your text input in your form.  Since you want the value as soon as the  datalist is selected, then you can use the `input` event.

Here is an example.  Just change `myTemplate` to the name of your template.

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  'input #search'(event) { 
    // get value for text input
    const value = event.currentTarget.value;

    // do something with value
  },
});
```

Check out this [meteor tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/forms-and-events) to learn more about form handling.

Comment: Thanks for help but its not working. I want to get value as soon as data is selected without click on any button.     For more help see my event handling code :     `'change #search':function (event, template) {
                               d = $(event.currentTarget).val();
                               console.log(d);`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I updated me answer accordingly. You can use the input event yo do this.

Comment: wow, Its work!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!. I got what i exactly want.... Ty sir , ty very much . I was really stuck with this from last 3 days. And finally i got it. I just changed my "change " to "input" and it work.   Ty again :D !!!!